# Want to compare and contrast the values of the matrix columns in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBI and I think my question might be very basic.

**Background of the question:**

I have created a matrix in PowerBI.

List of fields: SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP, WEEKDAY, PROJECT and AMOUNT.

The matrix has two layered columns: SNAPSHOT_TIMESTAMP and WEEKDAY ; row: PROJECT ; value: AMOUNT.

My objective is to compare and subtract two amounts based on current date. For example: if current_date = '10/12/2023' then I want to subtract the amount for snapshot of current_date(10/12/2023) from  the amount of the snapshot of previous_date(10/11/2023) for each week of October i.e., for 10/8/2023 (9637 - 9637 = 0) and for 10/22/2023 (2868246 - 2662108 = 206138) and for 10/29/2023 (970062 - 970062 = 0)

[image]

I have tried to search online but couldn't find any suitable answer for this question.